# My cookie still available after expiration

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am using `cookie-parser` to handle cookies on my express js app but I don't understand with the cookie isn't deleted after it is supposed to be expired.

I create my cookie like this more than 2 hours ago :

`res.cookie('foo', 'bar',{expire: 180000 + Date.now(),secure:true,httpOnly:true});`

but still available when I do: `req.cookies`

How it's possible? What I did wrong? How can I check the expiration time?

Comment: If you're using chrome, click the padlock icon (next to the URL) > cookies < your-URL > cookies > cookie-name to check the expiry date.

Comment: Yeah it's curious the expiration date is : "When you leave the browsing session" (translated from french version of chrome)